# Azure Functions: Configure Slf4j binding with Log4j2 and send logs to appinsights

Tags: azure-functions, log4j2, slf4j, azure-application-insights

I am using an Azure Function and I need to perform logging using **slf4j binding with log4j2**. I want my logs to get stored in application insights (Azure monitor). For this I have a log4j2.xml file for configuration, where I add the **ApplicationInsights Appender** and set the instrumentation key for the application insights resource.

Currently the behavior is that when I use ExecutionContext.getLogger.info("..."), I see the logs getting stored in app insights, **but this uses java.util.logging only.**
However, when I use the slf4j logger for logging, the logs are not getting stored in app insights, I can only see them on console.

What is the correct way to configure slf4j with log4j2 binding for sending logs to app-insights in Azure Functions? Is that possible, or do azure functions only support java.util.logging library for logging to appinsights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure function App logs into App Insights using slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67730720/azure-function-app-logs-into-app-insights-using-slf4j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of Azure Functions is to send logs to application insights using the java.util.logging library. The reason I was not seeing slf4j logs in application insights was that I had not excluded other logging libraries from my pom.xml.
After adding all exclusions, slf4j-log4j2 combination works fine and I can see the logs in my application insights resource.

Comment: Will it possible to add some sample pom.xml and logger configuration?